# Eigenvalues of a band matrix populated by all ones

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a square matrix $A$ of dimension $n$.  Suppose that $A$ is a band matrix with the band of length $\ell$ populated by all ones.

Recall that the band matrix is a matrix that is zero everywhere except on the band around the main diagonal.

Question: Can we find an expression for the eigenvalue of this matrix?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313115/explicit-calculation-of-eigenvalues-of-banded-toeplitz-matrix) answer help?